# ABAP Restful Application Programming Model (RAP) - Remove BT (between) operator from filters

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, rap

This is a know issue ABAP Restful Application Programming Model (RAP).

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/10/20/how-to-call-a-remote-odata-service-from-the-trial-version-of-sap-cloud-platform-abap-environment/comment-page-1/#comment-605901

The workaround is the replace the BT operator with separate LE and GE operators, but this only appears to work with a single BT, not multiples.

Coming at it from another angle, is there any way we could disable the Between and Not Between operators on the Fiori Elements / Free Style (Smart Filter) app side?

[image]

Comment: So the problem is that multiple "between" filters are ANDed not ORed? Or what's exactly the issue?

Answer (score 0):

at this point the solution may be using the expressed intervals.

from 01.01.2022 to 03.01.2022.

op.1) bt '01.01.2022' '03.01.2022'-

op.2) gt 01.01.2022 and le 03.01.2022

**op.3) date in ( '01.01.2022','02.01.2022','03.01.2022' ).**

is it suitable?